# SimpleDateFormat AM/PM conversion

Tags: android, datetime, simpledateformat

So, I'm trying to add AM/PM to `12:10:00`. Below is the code I'm using

```
SimpleDateFormat timeToString = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
```

I understand `hh` means 12 hours and `HH` is  24 hours.

But when i put the above mentioned value in

`String dateStr = timeToString.format(time);`

It gives me `12:10 am`

Shouldn't `00:10:00` be `12:00 am`?

**EDIT:**

Shouldn't `12:10` be converted to `12:10 PM`?

If yes, then how do I do it. If no, then whats the work around?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Yes, 12:10 on a 24 hour clock should be 12:10 PM on a 12 hour clock. To find out what you did wrong, please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time and ThreeTen Backport

```
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String time24Hour = "12:10:00";
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(time24Hour);
    String time12Hour = time.format(timeFormatter);
    System.out.println(time12Hour);
```

Output from this snippet is what you expected:

> 12:10 PM

Notice that your format pattern string, `hh:mm a`, is correct for *formatting*. I don’t know what you used for parsing, I suspect that your error may have been there.

I have added a locale to the formatter to control which language I get. Since AM and PM are hardly used in other languages than English, I chose `Locale.ENGLISH`, but please choose the locale that is right for you.

The `SimpleDateFormat` class that you used is notoriously troublesome and fortunately long outdated. Instead I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. This has the added bonus that parsing the 24 hour format goes smoothly without an explicit formatter. This is because the format you’ve got conforms with ISO 8601, the internation date and time standard. The modern classes parse (and also print) ISO 8601 format as their default.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Thank you for answering and clearly explaining everything. you the real MVP.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two components that you can use to display the 12 hours format:

- **K** for "Hour in am/pm (0-11)" -> will display: 00:50 PM
- **h** for "Hour in am/pm (1-12)" -> will display: 12:50 PM

Everything works as expected here. You now have to use the format that suits you best.

Comment: @OleV.V. i'm actually referring to Hours.

Comment: @Iulian Popescu, this doesn't solve it. What i'm asking is why is 12:10 converted to AM when its PM.

Comment: So, you have 12:10 (24 hour format) and your questions is why it is converted 12:10 PM (12 hour format)?